# Spring Autowiring of Parameterized Collection

Tags: java, spring

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.

I am having a problem where Spring cannot autowire a parametirized member variable of type ArrayBlockingQueue.

Here is the java code:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController
{
    @Autowired
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<SomeCustomType> myQueue;
}
```

and in the spring configuration xml:

```
<bean id="myQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Specifying the type (SomeCustomType) for the ArrayBlockingQueue seems to confuse spring which fails to find a match and does not perform the autowiring.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I know I can create my own wrapper class(around ArrayBlockingQueue) that is not parametirized but I would rather not if there is a better way to go about solving this.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? There is no reason this shouldn't work. You should realize though that since Spring instantiates the classes at runtime, parameterized types have no meaning to Spring - it can't see the parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is what I assumed too. Spring should not care about parametirized types but it does get confused by that.
 Here is part of the error message:
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue] found for dependency

Comment: You can try specify Autowire by name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to auto wire a collection with annotations, then use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`.

In order to satisfy an `@Autowired` collection dependency, the IoC container looks for elements of the right type to build such a collection from. In other words, it does not look for the collection itself, but rather builds a collection out of other beans.

For more information, see the Spring docs, ex. [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5038).