# Spring @Autowired value is not fully initialized

Tags: spring, autowired

Given the following code:

```
public class MyService implements InitializingBean {

  @Autowired
  private Set<MyDep> allDeps;

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    ... use 'allDeps' here ...
  }
}
```

`MyDep` is an interface with three different implementations all of which also implement `InitializingBean` (by extending the same abstract base class).

When I go to use `allDeps` during set up of `MyService` only 2 out of the 3 injected instances are themselves fully initialized.  One of the instances is constructed and injected, but it's `afterPropertiesSet()` has not yet been run.  In the other two instances it has been run.

It's been my understanding that Spring will run `afterPropertiesSet()` on a bean only after all of its dependencies are injected, and they will only be injected once they're fully initialized.  Perhaps my understanding is wrong?  Is this a bug in Spring?  I've also tried using `getBeansOfType(MyDep.class)` with the same results.

FWIW, looks like there's an similar unanswered question from 2 years ago.  So perhaps it's time to re-ask?
[Spring dependency injection not completing in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210919/spring-dependency-injection-not-completing-in-time)

Comment: I recommend to not implement the InitilizingBean interface. Instead look at the @PostConstruct annotation and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck.  In general I do prefer @PostConstruct.  But it this case it doesn't help anyway.  I think those methods are actually invoked at the same life-cycle point as (and actually prior to) any 'afterPropertiesSet()' method, so in terms of waiting for full initialization that's not going to make a difference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519187/spring-postconstruct-vs-init-method-attribute

Comment: Do any of the beans that were not picked up have a dependency on `MyService`?

Comment: Doh!  I thought I considered that thoroughly.  But I just now re-checked it and there it is.  That's exactly what it is.  A cyclic dependency (several layers deep) that was just luckily being avoided during context creation in the past.  Doh I say!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Given that it turns out there is a cyclic dependency in my bean definitions, the solution is to wait until the full context is created before doing the initialization in `MyService`.

Perhaps not the best solution, given that anything that depends on `MyService` in its set-up could have problems, but I don't currently have any of those.  So, this seems to do the trick for me:

```
public class MyService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Autowired
  private Set<MyDep> allDeps;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    ... now I can use 'allDeps' here ...
  }
}
```